# pass object by reference in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to call a function `getDate()` using `pass by reference`. In the function `lessThan()`, all the variables from object are fine, but I get an error when calling the object's function. Why am I getting that?

Error Message:

> This object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the
>   member function "CDate::getDate" object type is const CDate

ThisCopyNFriend.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Header.h"

class CDate
{
public:
    CDate(int, int, int);
    ~CDate();

    void getDate();

    bool lessThan(const CDate&);
    bool equal(const CDate&);
    bool greaterThan(const CDate&);

    CDate plus(const CDate&);
    CDate operator+(const CDate&);

    friend void greet(string);


private:
    int day, month, year;
};
```

ThisCopyNFriend.cpp:

```
#include "ThisCopyNFriend.h"

CDate::CDate(int _day = 1, int _month = 1, int _year = 1990)
{
    this->day = _day;
    this->month = _month

;
    this->year = _year;
}

CDate::~CDate()
{
}

void CDate::getDate() {
    cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year;
}

bool CDate::lessThan(const CDate &_cdate) {
    if (_cdate.year < this->year) {
        cout << "\n  ";
        _cdate.getDate();                // This is the bit that start to have error.
        cout << " is less then ";
        getDate();
        return true;
    } 
    else if(_cdate.month < this->month && _cdate.year == this->year) {
        cout << "\n  ";
        _cdate->getDate();
        cout << " is less then ";
        getDate();
        return true;
    }
    else if (_cdate.day < this->day && _cdate.month == this->month && _cdate.year == this->year) {
        cout << "\n  ";
        _cdate.getDate();
        cout << " is less then ";
        getDate();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "\n  ";
        getDate();
        cout << " is less then ";
        _cdate.getDate();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Open to any suggestions regarding to my code!!!

Comment: Change `void getDate();` to `void getDate() const;` since it does not modify the state of the object.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, thanks Eljay!!! that fixed it!!

Comment: Good deal, Daniel H explained the situation in detail.  You should accept his answer.

Comment: Yea I will, but the forum don't let me do that until 3 mins later. lol

Comment: Change "void getDate();" to "void showDate() const;"  since it is returning nothing, and performing some sort of cout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, "qualifiers" means `const` (or, rarely, `volatile`, but usually not). Thus, the error message is saying that an object is `const`, but `CDate::getDate` expects a non-`const` object. To fix that, you should tell the compiler that `getDate` doesn't actually modify the object it's called on, by making it `void CDate::getDate() const` instead of just `void CDate::getDate()`.

Comment: As `lessThan`, `equal` and `greaterThan` are not going to modify anything, you may add `const` to the end of all these functions (as in `getDate`. (Example: `bool CDate::equal() const`)

Comment: Thanks user3454439! Appreciate ur comment to the rest of the code!